# How to get text and image formatting with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code that uses IMAP functions to connect to a an email account's inbox, and get the first message then get the body of that message and post it to a MySQL table that manages news entries.

The problem is i need the formatting of text and images to be posted in the table as well. For example in the content column in the table which holds the message, i want it to have the bolding, italicized text, image location to be posted along with it as well. But as of right now it only gets the raw text of the email body.

I've looked all through the functions for imap http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php
but can't really find that specifies to getting the formatting of the e-mails other than the raw text.

Can somebody help me find a solution to solving this?

```
<?php

    /** Strictly must use e-mail format (Script to find e-mail is case senstiive, so follow as seen below

        News Update                             
        Title: Article Title                                
        Tags: tag1 tag2             //do not insert commas, use lowercase only
        Categories: Article Category, 2nd Article Category
        Snippet: Article snippet.                       
        Message: 
        Article Message. Images. More text, more text. Lorem impsum dolor sit amet.

    **/

        //IMAP Functions begin here (Before NewsUpdate function)
            //Accessing e-mail inbox
            $mailbox = '{server.com/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
            $mbox = imap_open($mailbox, 'user', 'password'); // log in to mail server



        $no = 2; //number of the e-mail message. Defined as first e-mail in the inbox (not a UID)
            $open_email_msg = imap_body($mbox, $no);


                    //This defines the function "NewsUpdate"
                    function NewsUpdate ($open_email_msg) 
                    {

                            //Login to MySQL Datebase
                            $hostname = "localhost";
                            $db_user = "user";
                            $db_password = "password";
                            $database = "database";
                            $db_table = "newsentries";

                            $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
                            mysql_select_db($database,$db);

                            //These functions searches the open e-mail for the the prefix defining strings.
                                //Need a function to search after the space after the strings because the subject, categories, snippet, tags and message are constant-changing.
                                $subject = preg_match('/Title: (.*)/', $open_email_msg, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
                                    $subject = str_replace("Title: ", "" ,$subject);

                                $categories = preg_match('/Categories: (.*)/', $open_email_msg, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';       //Searches the open e-mail for the string "Categories"
                                    $categories = str_replace("Categories: ", "" ,$categories);

                                $snippet = preg_match('/Snippet: (.*)/', $open_email_msg, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';                 //Searches the open e-mail for the string "Snippet"
                                    $snippet = str_replace("Snippet: ", "" ,$snippet);

    ##########################################################                              
                                $content = preg_match('/Message: (.*)/', $open_email_msg, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';             //Searches the open-email for the string "Message"
                                    $content = str_replace("Message: ", "" ,$content);

    #########################################################

                                //This defines the article's tags
                                $tags = str_replace(' ',',',$subject);  //DDIE

                                $when = strtotime("now");       //date article was posted


                            # THIS CODE WILL TELL MYSQL TO INSERT THE DATA FROM THE EMAIL INTO YOUR MYSQL TABLE
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(`caption`,`snippet`,`content`,`when`,`tags`,`categories`,`DATE`) values ('$subject','$snippet','$content','$when','$tags','$categories','$when')";
                            if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) {
                            } else {
                            echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
                            }
                            //echo "<h1>News Article added!</h1>"; //uncomment for testing purposes

                    }   //end definung the function NewsUpdate


                //This script that searches the e-mail for the string "News Update", and if it is found it will start the function NewsUpdate
                //if(strpos($open_email_msg,"News Update")) 
                    NewsUpdate ($open_email_msg);
    /*      else {
        echo "<b>News Update</b> not found in e-mail message!";
                    }
        */          
                //Deletes the email
    //          imap_delete($mbox, $no);
    //      imap_expunge($mbox);

            //closes the mailbox
        imap_close($mbox); 


    ?>
```

Comment: 'imap_body() will only return a verbatim copy of the message body. To extract single parts of a multipart MIME-encoded message you have to use imap_fetchstructure() to analyze its structure and imap_fetchbody() to extract a copy of a single body component.' - quote from the imap_body function. I advise you to open the structure of the mail and see which parts are sent. One of the parts should contain a body with formatted text.

Comment: @Pelshoff: if your last comment were an answer, I guess it would get accepted ;)

Comment: It's not an answer, it's just a pointer. I don't know the answer. But thanks for the up :)

Comment: i'll give it a shot and post back here what happens

Comment: I added the following
`$mailbox = '{server.com/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$mbox = imap_open($mailbox, 'user', 'pass'); // log in to mail server
$no = 2; //number of the e-mail message. Defined as first e-mail in the inbox (not a UID)
$content = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $no);
$open_email_msg = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $no, $content);`

and got this error message:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string on line 40 is the imap fetchbody line